# How do I make an A-Frame animation ease in and out correctly?

Tags: javascript, animation, aframe

After reading [A-Frame's animation docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html) and playing with different easing functions, I still can't make [this example](https://codepen.io/trentontri/pen/JQyNrE) pulse out *and* back in:

```
<a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
   <a-entity id="mouseCursor" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: #circle"></a-entity>
   <a-circle id="circle" color="black" position="0 1.8 -3" radius=".7" material="opacity: 0.5" animation="property: radius; from: 0; to: 0.7; dur: 1000; easing: easeInOutSine; loop: true;"></a-circle>
</a-scene>
```

Here is a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/trentontri/pen/ydoMzq) of how it should animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a [direction](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/animation.html#api_dir) for the animation - if you want it to alternate then use `dir: alternate`:

```
<a-circle id="circle" color="black" position="0 1.8 -3" radius=".7" material="opacity: 0.5" 
         animation="property: radius; from: 0.01; to: 0.7; dur: 1000;
         easing: easeInOutSine; dir: alternate; loop: true;"></a-circle>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/pnbq7ys2/4/).

---

also you can't make the radius go `0` because three will pop up an error:

```
THREE.DirectGeometry: Faceless geometries are not supported.
```

you can either change 0 -> 0.001, or animate the `scale` from `1 1 1` to `0 0 0`